# Add the Access Token in the Header of Edge Browser

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, access-token

I need to test my APIs using browser hence, there are any way to do add the access token in the browser header.

---

ex:

- Access Token: 'Bearer 4b21949a-4829-43cc-ada5-1d0512478676'
- Endpoint: http://localhost:8080/product

Comment: build a very simplistic website that contains only one button that cally your API and host it locally with xampp. That should give you everything you need for testing.

Comment: yeah, I used postman but, I'm trying to use chrome and edge..